# sorting not working on multi column horizontal jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport 3.1.1.

I've a report containing two columns. I've set report properties as :

```
Columns=2
```

and `Print order=Horizontal` (like a news paper style). Everything works but the sorting. I've added order by clause in query and also `<sortField name="my_sort_ORDER"/>` but still report shows sort order in zig zag instead of top to bottom for first column and then again from top to bottom for next column. Any ideas? Current data, current report out put, and expected report out put samples are below:

```
Name  Sort_Order
A      1
B      2
C      3
D      4
E      5

--Current report out put
Name   Sort Order     Name   Sort Order
A       1             B       2   
C       3             D       4 
E       5 

--Out put expected:
Name   Sort Order     Name   Sort Order
A       1             D       4   
B       2             E       5 
C       3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct output for your setting. 
That is what horizontal print order does: the report will be filled from left to right until the first row is complete, and only then pass to the next row and so on.

```
  value1     value2 
  value3     value4 
  value5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Then in my opinion iReport is interpretting it incorrectly. It should work in the same way as the news paper reading, which is we read first column from top to bottom and then we move to next column.